# Parse velocity variables within java

Tags: java, velocity

The following is an example of what I want to do.
I have a bunch of files such as test1.vm:

```
Welcome ${name}. This is test1.
```

Then I have a file called defaults.vm:

```
#set($name = "nmore")
```

I want render test1.vm (and the other test files) with the variable(s) in defaults.vm without using #parse as I would have to modify all the test files.

Is there a way to do this from within the accompanying java file?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7, why do you ask?

Comment: Sound like a job for a shell script. Would that work for you?

Comment: That would not work. New test files are added all the time and I can't keep running the script. Is there any way to do it within java?

Comment: Running java is more difficult than scheduling a shell script to run either every minute or as part of uploading the files. I wouldn't even consider doing this in java on a Linux box - it's a 5 minute programming job all up, and shell is more reliable than java. Windows is crap tho for operations type work, but there might be a way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have any constraints or any other specific requirements, but if you don't have you tried to use Velocity API? Something like this:

```
Context context = new VelocityContext();

Template template = Velocity.getTemplate("src/main/resources/defaults.vm");
template.merge(context, NullWriter.NULL_WRITER);

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
Template toBeParsedTemplate = Velocity.getTemplate("src/main/resources/test1.vm");
toBeParsedTemplate.merge(context, writer);

String renderedContent = writer.getBuffer().toString();
System.out.println(renderedContent);
```

The idea is that you fill in the `Context` object with the variables generated from `defaults.vm` and use the same context to evaluate `test1.vm`.

I've tried this using Velocity 1.7 and commons-io 2.4 (for the `NullWriter`) seems to be working fine, but I'm not sure if this can fit into your requirement or you're looking into other alternatvies (not using Velocity API).

More info on the `Context` object here: 
http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#The_Context

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried this but maybe I did it wrong. I will try again. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Ok this worked! This is exactly what I was looking for. Before I was making the mistake of having 2 contexts merging to 1 writer, but you actually want 1 context.